# How to assign roles (using check boxes) in fosuserbundle User Registration?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm using fosuserbundle for registration and login (authentication). I want to assign roles at registration time (using check boxes).

These three will be in form of Check boxes ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER, ROLE_SUPPER_ADMIN.

I created a User entity that extends baseUser. I have RegisterType extending BaseType.

I want to use fosuserbundle's role value, how do I link fosuserbundle's role with checkbox?

My security.yml is given below

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager 


        logout:      
         path:   /logout
         target:  /login
        anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/Services/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

What must I do now to achieve what I want?

Comment: What do you want to do? Your questions isn't clear on that. You've made a check box with Roles, do you want to add the role to the new created user depending on the choice you made on the checkbox?

Comment: Were any of the below contributions helpful, Zargham?

Comment: Regretfully downvoted (see above).

Answer (score 0):

Steps :

1. Add security roles in security.yml (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html).
2. Create an array and that inside form builder to create the checkbox combinations.
3. Inside controller, use this after user entity is created:
   $userEntity->setRoles([SELECTEDROLE VAUES IN POST VAR]);

SELECTEDROLE VAUES IN POST VAR === Values selected by the user during registration process.

Answer (score 0):

To assign roles at registration time You can add an Event Subscriber or an Event Listener to a Form Class and use the form event "formEvents::POST_SUBMIT"

[More details](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data)